# MongoDB sharding: host does not belong to replica set

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am a Mongo newbie.
I am trying to sping up a MongoDB cluster with both sharding and replication. Cluster schema which I want to implement is: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/raw/master/mongodb/images/site.png
I am using server IP as replication set name. I.e. I am building replication sets with commands below:

```
rs.initiate()
rs.add("10.148.28.51:27118")
rs.add("10.148.28.52:27118")
rs.add("10.148.28.53:27118")
```

Replication is being configured correctly so when I am executing rs.status() on PRIMARY host 10.148.28.51 I am getting "10.148.28.51" as repl.set name: https://gist.github.com/daniilyar/630bc6fe7723ed06f243

But when I am trying to add shards at mongos instance it gives me 2 opposite errors (depending on what addShard() syntax variation I use):

```
mongos> sh.addShard("10.148.28.51:27118")
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "host is part of set 10.148.28.51, use replica set url format     <setname>/<server1>,<server2>,...."
}
mongos> sh.addShard("10.148.28.51/10.148.28.51:27118") 
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "in seed list 10.148.28.51/10.148.28.51:27118, host 10.148.28.51:27118 does not belong to replica set 10.148.28.51"
}
```

How do I add shard if Mongo tells that "host X is in replica set Y" and that "host X does not belong to replica set Y" in the same time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From your description sounds like you need to tweak the way your are using the rs.add(..) command. You state you are using the IP address as the name of the replica set but this is not how rs.add(...) interprets the argument.

The argument you pass is the hostname (or IP) and port of the mongod instance you are looking to add to the replica set **not**the replica set name. You set-up this configuration when connected via mongo to the primary. The  replSet name is set when the primary is started:

```
mongod --replSet "rs1"
```

sets the as name of **rs1**.

I'd have a read over: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/ as it covers pretty much what you appear to be trying to do.

I'd also consider what you are trying to achieve as it sounds (from your description) like you may end up with a single replicated shard (!!!) when you most probably are looking to create multiple shards each of which have their data replicated.

**References**:

rs.add command - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.add/

rs.addShard command - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.addShard/
Sharded Cluster - 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/

Comment: But when I am executing rs.status() command on PRIMARY at host 10.148.28.51 I am getting "10.148.28.51" as repl.set name: https://gist.github.com/daniilyar/630bc6fe7723ed06f243
I've edited the question to reflect that and also added the schema for cluster which I want to build.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for good explanation, now I understand. If you use in rs.add(IP:port), Mongo adds replica set member with name ip-X-Y-Z-R:. It seems to be Mongo's default behavior. So in my case solution was to use command:

```
sh.addShard("10.148.28.51/**ip-10-148-28-51**:27118")
```

instead of:

```
sh.addShard("10.148.28.51/**10.148.28.51**:27118")
```